# Python - how to get JSON from a GraphQL api?

Tags: python, python-requests, graphql

I'm trying to create a simple Python script that should just query a GraphQL api and retrieve JSON data from it. The problem with my code is that i keep getting an HTML response whereas i need to get JSON data.

If i execute the GraphQL api from [here](https://graph.defikingdoms.com/subgraphs/name/defikingdoms/apiv5/graphql?query=%7BsaleAuctions(allowedAddresses%3A%20%5B%220xdc65d63cdf7b03b95762706bac1b8ee0af130e8b%22%2C%20%220x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000%22%5D)%20%7Bid%7D%7D), the page will receive a JSON response (i can see it from Chrome devtools as well), but if i do the same from my Python code, i will get an html response:

```
import requests
import json
import time

query = {'query': '{saleAuctions(allowedAddresses: ["0xdc65d63cdf7b03b95762706bac1b8ee0af130e8b", "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]) {id}}'}
r = requests.get('https://graph.defikingdoms.com/subgraphs/name/defikingdoms/apiv5', params=query)

print(r.headers['content-type'])
```

Response: `text/html`

I tried to send the query as a POST request payload, but the output is the same. How can i retrieve the JSON data from my Python script too? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send a POST request with a json body.

```
import requests
import json
import time

query = json.dumps({'query': '{saleAuctions(allowedAddresses: ["0xdc65d63cdf7b03b95762706bac1b8ee0af130e8b", "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]) {id}}'})
r = requests.post('https://graph.defikingdoms.com/subgraphs/name/defikingdoms/apiv5', data=query)

print(r.headers['content-type'])
```